# Inelegant log in vue-cli project?

Tags: node.js

When I exit vue-cli project, its exit log is extremely inelegant, look like below pic, how to slient log warning?

[image]

Comment: It's a Node v12.5.0 issue which is generally better solved by checking their issues list ~ https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/28479

Comment: thanks, it's bug of v12.5.0, upgrade to v12.6.0 is solved this problem